# Trouble starting my car

Tags: starting, vw, jetta

In the morning my Vw Jetta doesn’t start. Later in the afternoon it starts and works perfectly fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be a huge number of things. Temp sensor, coil, ignition module, fuel pump just to name a few. Is the check engine light on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What type of engine in your Jetta? Ultimately it sounds like it starts ... do you crank and crank, or just wait until the vehicle has warmed up via ambient air?

Comment: It’s a Vw Jetta 2005 Tdi 1.9L. The check engine light is on. I wait until the glow plug light turns off and try to start. The engine comes on for like half a second then turns off.